# SAPUI5 make the whole row clickable for sap.m.Panel

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

In an XML view I have an expandable `Panel`. Here, I can expand the panel only with clicking the arrow icon.

Is there a way to make the icon AND the whole `Panel` clickable?

Here's a snippet for a simple `Panel`:
http://jsbin.com/wamutodubu/1/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62170934/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a delegate. Add the id "panel" to your panel and this to your controller:

```
onInit: function() {
  var panel = this.byId("panel");
  panel.addDelegate({
    onclick: function(oEvent) {
      if (oEvent.target === panel.$().find(".sapMPanelHdr").get(0)) {
        panel.setExpanded(!panel.getExpanded());
      }

    }
});
```

I changed your JSBin: http://jsbin.com/qetaxexoli/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's interesting to see that it _is_ possible. However don't you think it's not good to check the style class `sapMPanelHdr`, as it _may_ be changed by the framework at a later point in time ?

Comment: That is true. The CSS and the class names are not part of the API and a change would thus not be considered incompatible. I don't see a way to do what is asked by only using API - and since this feature not working would only be a minor inconvenience I wouldn't consider it problematic if I saw it used like that in an App.