# sap.m.Panel: make entire header clickable

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have `sap.m.Panel` and I want to enable expand / collapse where the user click on the header. But this event only fires when the user clicks on the arrow.

Any idea of how to solve it?

This is my code:

```js
var panel = new Panel(); // Panel required from "sap/m/Panel"
panel.setExpandable(true);
panel.setHeaderText("someText");
```

Comment: It's supported out of the box since 1.79. Otherwise, an active headerTitle can be added. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62170934/5846045

Comment: Is there anything else missing from the answers? Otherwise, it would be nice if one of them could be accepted to let others know that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

## UI5 ≥ 1.79

Since 1.79, the entire header of `sap.m.Panel` is clickable by default.<sup>1</sup>

## UI5 1.78 and below

Add a headerToolbar and set its `active` property to `true`. On press, toggle the `expanded` property value with `panel.setExpanded(!panel.getExpanded())`:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/Panel",
  "sap/m/Toolbar",
  "sap/m/Title",
  "sap/m/Text",
], (Panel, Toolbar, Title, Text) => {

  const panel = new Panel({
    expandable: true,
    headerToolbar: new Toolbar({
      active: true,
      content: new Title({ text: "Panel Header" }),
      press: () => panel.setExpanded(!panel.getExpanded()),
    }),
    content: new Text({ text: "Panel content" }),
  }).placeAt("content");

}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Commit: [`d8741f3`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d8741f3bebd87d24a08b93e37f9eaae9c0a54455)

Answer (score 1):

We had the similar requirement and we made it to work with following logic:
1. Add a headerToolbar to Panel.
2. Attach click event on the headerToolbar.
3. onClickHandler check if the Panel is already expanded. If yes, collpase or expand the panel.

Below is the code. Let me know if this helps:

XML :

```
        <Panel 
            expandable='true' expanded='false'>
            <headerToolbar>
                            <Toolbar id='idPanelHeader'>
                                <content>
                                    <Text text='Click Me!' />
                                </content>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </headerToolbar>
            <content>
                <Text text = 'Hey' />
            </content>
        </Panel>
```

Controller ( did it in OnInit):

```
      var oPanelHeader = this.byId('idPanelHeader');
      oPanelHeader.attachBrowserEvent("click", function() {
          this.getParent().setExpanded(!this.getParent().getExpanded());
          // this points to HeaderToolbar and this.getParent will return the Panel.
      });
```